# After upgrading to PHP 5.5 from 3.x, it seems to be trying to parse my JavaScript comment (embedded in a script tag in a PHP include file)

Tags: javascript, php

I havent worked with PHP in quite some time, but the first website I ever built, I did with PHP, and I used `include` for everything. Until the web host updated PHP, everything worked, and now there's no option to revert back to the older version of PHP. I just need to fix this weird bug caused by the update to 5.5, where it *seems* php is trying to parse the javascript.

So I used `include` to separate the `<head>` section, and the PHP file containing the script tags for inclusion is as follows:

`scripts.php`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/nav.js"></script>
<script>
  .. snip ..

</script>
<script>
    var imgId = [
                "ip-product-1",
                "ip-product-2",
                "ip-product-3",
                "ip-product-4",
            ];

            var ImageCnt = 0;
            function IPnextImage(direction) 
            {
                    var i=1;
                    while(i<5)
                    {

                    document.getElementById("ip-product-" + i).style.opacity = "0"; 
                    document.getElementById("ip-product-" + i).style.pointerEvents = "none";
                    i++;
                    }
                // ImageCnt set to: ImageCnt plus (if direction is left)<-1>(else)<1> - in other words, for "left" subtract one from ImageCnt and for "right" add one to it, and then convert this to <%> to keep anything from escaping the maximum or minimum. 
                ImageCnt = (ImageCnt + (direction == "left" ? imgId.length-1 : 1)) % imgId.length;
                document.getElementById(imgId[ImageCnt]).style.opacity = "1";
                document.getElementById(imgId[ImageCnt]).style.pointerEvents = "auto";  
            }       
</script>
```

And then I just use `scripts.php` with `include` to form the document.

But now there's an error: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '>' in /hermes/waloraweb089/b2700/as.agcomput/AGWebsite1.2/includes/scripts.php on line 73`

Line 73 is:

```
ImageCnt = (ImageCnt + (direction == "left" ? imgId.length-1 : 1)) % imgId.length; 
// ImageCnt set to: ImageCnt plus (if direction is left)<-1>(else)<1> - in other 
// words, for "left" subtract one from ImageCnt and for "right" add one to it, 
// and then convert this to <%> to keep anything from escaping the maximum or minimum.
```

What's going on in PHP 5.5 for this to be a problem wheras is worked back in PHP 3.x?

Comment: Note the update, id forgotten to include the comment associated with the line of code.

Comment: <% on the line before is an ASP open tag which is recognised by PHP.  Everything after that point is being parsed as PHP.

Comment: @nemmy but why wouldnt that have been caught back in PHP 3.3? Because there was no issue before. Perhaps I had changed PHP's settings to save time escaping characters and the settings were reset on update? Is there such a setting I couldve used?

Comment: I have no idea, before my PHP time, I just know it's an open PHP tag.

Comment: ` <%` is, uh, on by default now. short_tag(s) was disabled by default before PHP 5.something.

Comment: @Brian that must be the answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upgraded from PHP 3.x to PHP 5.5, you most likely got a brand new php.ini file, which may have enabled the [asp_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.asp-tags) setting.

Also note that this ASP style tag will be removed from PHP 7.0.0, so it's a safe bet to disable this config option.